# Toggle field in Angular Reactive form (form validation) based on a checkbox in a different component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I have a complex form which fields are based on toggling checkboxes in a different component (parent). I need to validate the form meaning that some fields might be disabled and some not. I need this to be dynamic and changes based on the ticking/unticking of the checkboxes, rather than have it working just for initialization. I have tried multiple examples with no luck..

parent.component.html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" ng-model="checked" (click)='toggleCheckform()'>
<label for="check">Check me</label>

<mat-tab label="child">
   <child [isCheck]="toggleCheck" (messageToEmit)="getMessage($event)"></child>
</mat-tab>
```

parent.component.ts

```
export class ParentComponent {

    constructor() { }

    toggleCheck: boolean = false;

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    toggleCheckform() {
        this.toggleCheck = !this.toggleCheck;
    }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() isCheck: boolean;

  testForm = this.fb.group({
    Field1: ['', Validators.required],
    Field2: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  get Field1() { return this.testForm.get('Field1'); }
  get Field2() { return this.testForm.get('Field2'); }

  if(isCheck){
    this.testForm.get('Field1').disable();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.warn(this.testForm.value);
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

child.component.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div *ngIf="isCheck">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="Field1">Field1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Field1" formControlName="Field1">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Field2">Field2</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Field2" formControlName="Field2">
    </div>

    </form>
```

So based on the checkbox on the parent component I want to be able to enable/disable that form field for validation. Tried a lot of approaches, the example works when the form is initialized but after it does not. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use a "setter" in the input

```
_isCheck:boolean
@Input() 
set isCheck(value)
{
  this._isCheck=true;
  const control=this.testForm.get('Field1')
  if(control)
  {
    if (value)
      control.enable();
    else
      control.disable();
   }
}

get isCheck()
{
    return this._isCheck
}
```

NOTE: when you disabled a FormControl the form.value NOT include the value (you need use [form.getRawValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue)) futhermore, the form is valid whatever the value of the formControl disabled was

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hg4gdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: tried exactly what you said and now the checkbox toggle button in main component is not working. I check and uncheck and nothing happens

Comment: ::glups:: I interchange the disabled/enabled, just correct in code. I add a stackblitz. If you fill Field2 and left the Filed1 empty, and check/uncheck you see that the form is valid or not